# Why property "primaryGroupID" missing for domain controller

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

I am trying to retrieve all DCs from domain and would also like to know if they are readable or writable.

To know if DC is readable or not, I need to read attribute **primaryGroupID** value for DC. Trying same in code below.

Code snippet -

```
 var currDomain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();

 foreach (DomainController dc in currDomain.DomainControllers)
        {
            var dcName = dc.Name;
            var de = dc.GetDirectoryEntry(); // DirectoryEntry represent DC

            // Loads the values of the specified properties into the property cache.
            de.RefreshCache(new[] {"primaryGroupID"});

           if (de.Properties.Contains("primaryGroupID"))
            {
                int primaryGroupID;
                var strPrimaryGroupID = Convert.ToString(de.Properties["primaryGroupID"][0]);

                if (int.TryParse(strPrimaryGroupID, out primaryGroupID))
                {
                    // RID for the "Read-only Domain Controllers" built-in group in Active Directory
                    // Writable Domain Controllers have primaryGroupID set to 516 (the "Domain Controllers" group).
                    dcName = string.Format(primaryGroupID == 521 ? "{0} (Read only)" : "{0} (Writable)", dc.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

However still property don't show up. I had confirmed from AD that the respective attribute exists for DC.

The default properties that show up are shown in screenshot below -

[image: List of default properties]

Do you have any clue why the property **primaryGroupID** is missing?

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please share how you would do that for **de** object in code-snippet I shared?

Comment: What is the objectClass of the DirectoryEntry that you get from dc.GetDirectoryEntry()? The primaryGroupID attribute may not be valid for that type of object.

Comment: I just tried it myself. It returns a "server" object. The primaryGroupID attribute isn't valid for server objects.

Answer (score 0):

dc.GetDirectoryEntry() returns a server object, not the computer object of the DC. And primaryGroupID doesn't exist on server objects. But it does contain a reference to the computer object. Try this:

```
var dcDe = dc.GetDirectoryEntry(); // DirectoryEntry represent DC
var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + dcDe.Properties["serverReference"].Value);

if (de.Properties.Contains("primaryGroupID"))
...
```